# Question in Page 47 of Elementary Number theory by David Burton

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am studying Elementary number theory from David Burton Elementary number theory and I am unable to think about this argument which author gives in Ch-3 Primes and their Distribution.

> Author writes if $ p_n$ denotes n th prime then Euclid proof shows that expression $ p_1 p_2 ... p_n +1 $ is divisible by at least 1 prime and if there are several such prime divisiors, then $ p_{ n+1} $ cannot exceed the smallest of these so that $ p_{ n+1} \leq p_1 p_2 ... p_n +1 $ for $n\geq 1$ . Another way of saying is $ p_{ n} \leq p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1} +1 $ for $n\geq 2 $

I understand the argument completely but I am unable to think how to prove next line which is

> With a slight modification of Euclid reasoning, this inequality can be improved to give $ p_{ n} \leq p_1 p_2 ... p_{n-1}  -1 $ for all $ n \geq 3 $ .

Can someone please tell how to prove it.

Comment: Well, $p_1\cdots p_{n-1}-1$ is divisible by some prime  which can't be one of $p_1, \cdots, p_{n-1}$ so...

Comment: @lulu got it thanks!!

Comment: For n=2, we get $p_1...p_{n-1}-1=2-1=1$ so it doesn't work. We must suppose $n\geq 3$ in this case.